# LVM snapshot of mounted filesystem

Tags: linux, backup, filesystems, snapshot

I'd like to programmatically make a snapshot of a live filesystem in Linux, preferably using LVM. I'd like not to unmount it because I've got lots of files opened (my most common scenario is that I've got a busy desktop with lots of programs).

I understand that because of kernel buffers and general filesystem activity, data on disk might be in some more-or-less undefined state.

Is there any way to "atomically" unmount an FS, make an LVM snapshot and mount it back? It will be ok if the OS will block all activity for few seconds to do this task. Or maybe some kind of atomic "sync+snapshot"? Kernel call?

I don't know if it is even possible...

Comment: I was on the LVM mailing list for awhile, and I seem to remember that filesystems are supposed to have hooks to be called to force the filesystem to checkpoint itself (i.e. set it up so that all journal entries are played for a journaled fs) just before an LVM snapshot operation.  This would make sure the filesystem itself at least was in a consistent state in the snapshot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't have to do anything for most Linux filesystems.  It should just work without any effort at all on your part.  The snapshot command itself hunts down mounted filesystems using the volume being snapshotted and calls a special hook that checkpoints them in a consistent, mountable state and does the snapshot atomically.

Older versions of LVM came with a set of VFS lock patches that would patch various filesystems so that they could be checkpointed for a snapshot.  But with new kernels that should already be built into most Linux filesystems.

This [intro on snapshots](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshotintro.html) claims as much.

And a little more research reveals that for kernels in the 2.6 series the ext series of filesystems should all support this.  ReiserFS probably also.  And if I know the btrfs people, that one probably does as well.

Comment: Of course, if you are making LVM snapshots of a btrfs partion, you're being rather silly. Btrfs handles all that better than LVM could. And btrfs doesn't need any checkpointing hook because of how it works. Either you get the superblock pointing at the new root or you don't. Of course, it probably does have such a hook, but it's almost superfluous.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any way to "atomically" unmount an FS, make an LVM snapshot and mount it back?

It is possible to snapshot a mounted filesystem, even when the filesystem is not on an LVM volume. If the filesystem is on LVM, or it has built-in snapshot facilities (e.g. btrfs or ZFS), then use those instead.

The below instructions are fairly low-level, but they can be useful if you want the ability to snapshot a filesystem that is not on an LVM volume, and can't move it to a new LVM volume. Still, they're not for the faint-hearted: if you make a mistake, you may corrupt your filesystem. Make sure to consult [the official documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/device-mapper/snapshot.txt) and `dmsetup` man page, triple-check the commands you're running, and **have backups**!

The Linux kernel has an awesome facility called the Device Mapper, which can do nice things such as create block devices that are "views" of other block devices, and of course snapshots. It is also what LVM uses under the hood to do the heavy lifting.

In the below examples I'll assume you want to snapshot `/home`, which is an ext4 filesystem located on `/dev/sda2`.

First, find the name of the device mapper device that the partition is mounted on:

```
# mount | grep home
/dev/mapper/home on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

Here, the device mapper device name is `home`. If the path to the block device does not start with `/dev/mapper/`, then you will need to create a device mapper device, and remount the filesystem to use that device instead of the HDD partition. You'll only need to do this once.

```
# dmsetup create home --table "0 $(blockdev --getsz /dev/sda2) linear /dev/sda2 0"
# umount /home
# mount -t ext4 /dev/mapper/home /home
```

Next, get the block device's device mapper table:

```
# dmsetup table home
home: 0 3864024960 linear 9:2 0
```

Your numbers will probably be different. The device target should be `linear`; if yours isn't, you may need to take special considerations. If the last number (start offset) is not 0, you will need to create an intermediate block device (with the same table as the current one) and use that as the base instead of `/dev/sda2`.

In the above example, `home` is using a single-entry table with the `linear` target. You will need to replace this table with a new one, which uses the `snapshot` target.

Device mapper provides three targets for snapshotting:

- The `snapshot` target, which saves writes to the specified COW device. (Note that even though it's called a snapshot, the terminology is misleading, as the snapshot will be writable, but the underlying device will remain unchanged.)
- The `snapshot-origin` target, which sends writes to the underlying device, but also sends the old data that the writes overwrote to the specified COW device.

Typically, you would make `home` a `snapshot-origin` target, then create some `snapshot` targets on top of it. This is what LVM does. However, a simpler method would be to simply create a `snapshot` target directly, which is what I'll show below.

Regardless of the method you choose, you **must not** write to the underlying device (`/dev/sda2`), or the snapshots will see a corrupted view of the filesystem. So, as a precaution, you should mark the underlying block device as read-only:

```
# blockdev --setro /dev/sda2
```

This won't affect device-mapper devices backed by it, so if you've already re-mounted `/home` on `/dev/mapper/home`, it should not have a noticeable effect.

Next, you will need to prepare the COW device, which will store changes since the snapshot was made. This has to be a block device, but can be backed by a sparse file. If you want to use a sparse file of e.g. 32GB:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=0 seek=32768 of=/home_cow
# losetup --find --show /home_cow
/dev/loop0
```

Obviously, the sparse file shouldn't be on the filesystem you're snapshotting :)

Now you can reload the device's table and turn it into a snapshot device:

```
# dmsetup suspend home && \
  dmsetup reload home --table \
    "0 $(blockdev --getsz /dev/sda2) snapshot /dev/sda2 /dev/loop0 PO 8" && \
  dmsetup resume home
```

If that succeeds, new writes to `/home` should now be recorded in the `/home_cow` file, instead of being written to `/dev/sda2`. Make sure to monitor the size of the COW file, as well as the free space on the filesystem it's on, to avoid running out of COW space.

Once you no longer need the snapshot, you can merge it (to permanently commit the changes in the COW file to the underlying device), or discard it.

- To merge it:

  1. replace the table with a `snapshot-merge` target instead of a `snapshot` target:

     ```
     # dmsetup suspend home && \
       dmsetup reload home --table \
         "0 $(blockdev --getsz /dev/sda2) snapshot-merge /dev/sda2 /dev/loop0 P 8" && \
       dmsetup resume home
     ```
  2. Next, monitor the status of the merge until all non-metadata blocks are merged:

     ```
     # watch dmsetup status home
     ...
     0 3864024960 snapshot-merge 281688/2097152 1104
     ```

     Note the 3 numbers at the end (X/Y Z). The merge is complete when X = Z.
  3. Next, replace the table with a linear target again:

     ```
     # dmsetup suspend home && \
       dmsetup reload home --table \
         "0 $(blockdev --getsz /dev/sda2) linear /dev/sda2 0" && \
       dmsetup resume home
     ```
  4. Now you can dismantle the loop device:

     ```
     # losetup -d /dev/loop0
     ```
  5. Finally, you can delete the COW file.

     ```
     # rm /home_cow
     ```
- To discard the snapshot, unmount `/home`, follow steps 3-5 above, and remount `/home`. Although Device Mapper will allow you to do this without unmounting `/home`, it doesn't make sense (since the running programs' state in memory won't correspond to the filesystem state any more), and it will likely corrupt your filesystem.

Comment: When I read "even when the filesystem is not on an LVM volume", I thought "this will be some good devicemapper black magic!" Magnificent! One question though—will this procedure trigger the same hooks that will ensure the snapshot is in a consistent state? I assume it would have to be part of the `blockdev --setro /dev/sda2` call.

Comment: You could add a `sync` call just before creating the snapshot, however since I can't find any reliable source on whether `sync` acts above or below the filesystem layer, that may or may not do anything. Regardless of that, the snapshot *will* be consistent in the meaning that all changes that will or will not be included in the snapshot will be delimited strictly by a point in time, and not e.g. disk offset or file name, so the snapshot will appear as if the machine had its power cut at that moment, as it should. [...]

Comment: [...] This is sufficient e.g. for ACID databases to continue maintaining their data integrity. And unless you're using a non-journaling filesystem (ext3 and newer are journaling), I think filesystem corruption is also highly unlikely regardless whether filesystem caches have been flushed.

Comment: Seems like it doesn't, though. LVM does it here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/md/lvm.c?v=2.4.37#L2251. `blockdev --setro` eventually calls http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/block/ioctl.c#L432, and it seems like just adding a call similar to the one from LVM would do the trick.

Comment: "you will need to create a device mapper device [...]. You'll only need to do this once." How do I do that in a way that will actually persist across reboots? The proposed way will have to be done again after each reboot...

Comment: "If the last number (start offset) is not 0, you will need to create an intermediate block device" - could you elaborate why this is needed? And what would happen if you didn't do it?

Comment: @jurez Because typically DM targets (`snapshot` and `snapshot-origin` included) don't take a parameter for the start of the device they're based on. The `linear` target does, though. Essentially you need to first slice off the part of the disk (`sda2` in that example) that you need to work with. In practice I think this should never be an issue because when you mount a partition, you're going to use the data from the entire partition.

Comment: This is an awesome answer! Many thanks!! It's so difficult to find good resources about how to use disk mapper. Would upvote many times more if I could!

Answer (score 5):

I know that ext3 and ext4 in RedHat Enterprise, Fedora and CentOS automatically checkpoint when a LVM snapshot is created. That means there is never any problem mounting the snapshot because it is always clean.

I *believe* XFS has the same support. I am not sure about other filesystems.

Comment: "_RedHat Enterprise, Fedora and CentOS automatically checkpoint when a LVM snapshot is created_" : any documentation to prove this ? Is that specific to RH ?

Comment: @Benoît: "many of the filesystems in the 2.6 kernel do this automatically when a snapshot is created" -- http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshotintro.html

Comment: Well, this is actually quite new http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_2_6_29#head-b6c330f9e6d252b514138f042ac9b01e9d4170ca !

Comment: "RedHat Enterprise, Fedora and CentOS" - and which version of those would that be?

Comment: @0x89: Today in 2014 it is supported on everything recent. So use a modern Linux distro.

Comment: That is not of great help when I'm on a system with a specific version, upgrade is not in my own power, and I just want to know if the feature is supported on that system or not..

Comment: @0x89: Do a LVM snapshot. Mount it. If it had to do a journal recovery, your OS and filesystem does not automatically checkpoint.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the filesystem you are using. With XFS you can use `xfs_freeze -f` to sync and freeze the FS, and `xfs_freeze -u` to activate it again, so you can create your snapshot from the frozen volume, which should be a save state.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will do the trick for you, but you can remount a file system as read-only.  `mount -o remount,ro /lvm` (or something similar) will do the trick.  After you are done your snapshot, you can remount read-write using `mount -o remount,rw /lvm`.

Comment: This is possible only when no file is opened for writing... with a desktop, lots of files are, even though apps aren't writing to them all the time; f.e. sqlite databases of firefox and other apps.

Answer (score -1):

FS corruption is "highly unlikely", as long as you never work in any kind of professional environment. otherwise you'll meet reality, and you might try blaming "bit rot" or "hardware" or whatever, but it all comes down to having been irresponsible. **freeze/thaw** (as mentioned a few times, and only if called properly) is sufficient *outside* of database environments. for databases, you still won't have a transaction-complete backup and if you think a backup that rolls back some transaction is fine when restored: see starting sentence.
depending on the activity you might just added **another** 5-10 mins of downtime if ever you need that backup.
*Most* of us can easily afford that, but it can not be general advice. 
**Be honest about downsides, guys.**

Comment: Thank you for your note. However, please do not add comments to other answers as separate answers. That's what comments are for in the StackExchange platform. I suggest you add the part about file system corruption as a comment to Vladimir Panteleev's answer (which I assume you refer to), and the part about databases would be better placed as a comment to the question itself.